# Magento2: How can update & create the CMS static Page programmatically

Tags: magento2, programmatically, cms-pages, data-install

How can update an existing CMS static Page and how to create a new CMS static Page - programmatically

Comment: By module or by theme please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here is an example how to insert cms data in m2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/InstallData.php#L101)

[Here is an example how to update cms data in m2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/UpgradeData.php#L244)

Now you can try following way for insert cms data:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory
) {
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
}
```

And now:

```
$cmsPage = [
    'title' => 'TEST TITLE',
    'identifier' => 'test-content-1',
    'page_layout' => '1column',
    'content' => 'test content 1',
    'is_active' => 1,
    'store_id' => [0],
    'sort_order' => 22
];
$this->pageFactory->create()->setData($cmsPage)->save();
$setup->endSetup();
```

For Update:

```
$newPageContent = 'NEW PAGE CONTENT';
$newPage = $this->pageFactory->create()->load(
    'test-content-1',
    'identifier'
);
if ($newPage->getId()) {
    $newPage->setContent($newPageContent);
    $newPage->save();
}
```

Comment: Is 'identifier' the 'store_id' in above update section?

Comment: @harri no, the identifier is another column. If you want to particular store data, then just add setStore($storeId) above.

Comment: I got i think thanks, I changed the identifier to page_id and then used the id rather than identifier as had duplicate identifiers across stores.

Answer (score 3):

In Magento 2.3.x, Magento has introduced the DataPatchInterface to add/modify the data. You can programmatically create/modify the cms page in your custom module using a data patch.

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

class AddMyCmsPage implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    private $pageFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page
     */
    private $pageResource;

    /**
     * AddNewCmsPage constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     * @param \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page $pageResource
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page $pageResource
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->pageResource = $pageResource;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $pageIdentifier = 'test';
        $pageData = [
            'title' => 'Test Page',
            'page_layout' => '1column',
            'meta_keywords' => '',
            'meta_description' => '',
            'identifier' => $pageIdentifier,
            'content_heading' => '',
            'content' => 'This is my test page.',
            'layout_update_xml' => '',
            'url_key' => $pageIdentifier,
            'is_active' => 1,
            'stores' => [0],
            'sort_order' => 0
        ];

        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();
        $this->pageFactory->create()->setData($pageData)->save();
        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

You can refer full post [in this article.](http://www.codextblog.com/code-snippet/how-to-add-a-cms-page-programmatically-using-data-patch-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
namespace namespace\module\Model\StoreCreation;

use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;

class StoreDemoCreation
{

private $pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    PageFactory $pageFactory
)
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
}

public function duplicateDemo($store_id)
{
    $testPage = [
        'title' => 'Test page title',
        'identifier' => 'test-page',
        'stores' => [$store_id],
        'is_active' => 1,
        'content_heading' => 'Test page heading',
        'content' => 'Test page content',
        'page_layout' => '1column'
    ];

    $this->pageFactory->create()->setData($testPage)->save();
}
```

}

Comment: I think they are extra here: `use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;`

Comment: you right i will edit it