# How to create a custom CMS static block programmatically and have it be displayed on homepage?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.6

I am able to create CMS Static Block from admin and display it on the homepage, but is there a way to do it programmatically so I can create custom widgets(basically custom HTML/CSS) and display it on the homepage? What's the best way to go about displaying Custom HTML/CSS on the homepage programmatically? Or is modifying the `Content` in `Content>Pages>Home Page` is the only way?

Comment: you can create block programmatically find [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127495/how-to-add-a-cms-block-programmatically-in-magento-2) or [this](https://webkul.com/blog/create-cms-block-installer-magento-2/) one, let me find to assign it into the homepage

Comment: try [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194408/magento2-how-can-update-create-the-cms-static-page-programmatically/194414) one, it maybe solve your problem, I think you just need to get first cms page content and after that update to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create **InstallData.php** file at `/app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(BlockFactory $blockFactory)
    {
        $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $cmsBlockData = [
            'title' => 'Custom CMS Block',
            'identifier' => 'custom_cms_block',
            'content' => "<h1>Your content added here</h1>",
            'is_active' => 1,
            'stores' => [0],
            'sort_order' => 0
        ];

        $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($cmsBlockData)->save();
    }
}
```

Then, remove your module value from **setup_module** table and related table also. Now, execute this below command.

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f or php bin/magento s:s:d
php bin/magento c:c
```

Then, go to **admin -> Content -> Blocks** and find your static block will be created. Now, add your changes if you need.

Hope, it will helpful for you.

Comment: In the content part- `'content' => "<h1>Your content added here</h1>"`, can I call another phtml file so the contents of that phtml file gets displayed? Or should I write my entire html/CSS/JS in InstallData.php file?

Comment: Yes. You can add phtml like this 'content' => "<p>{{block class="VendorName\ModuleName\Block\BlockFileName" template="VendorName_ModuleName::yourphtml.phtml"}}</p>"